# Which folder should I put my static files in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

While I am looking the doc. I saw the following document structure,

```
.
├── _config.yml
├── _drafts
|   ├── begin-with-the-crazy-ideas.textile
|   └── on-simplicity-in-technology.markdown
├── _includes
|   ├── footer.html
|   └── header.html
├── _layouts
|   ├── default.html
|   └── post.html
├── _posts
|   ├── 2007-10-29-why-every-programmer-should-play-nethack.textile
|   └── 2009-04-26-barcamp-boston-4-roundup.textile
├── _data
|   └── members.yml
├── _site
├── .jekyll-metadata
└── index.html
```

When I need to include an image inside my post. Where should I put the image to use the feature of `site.static_files` mentioned [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/) (Static Files Section in the Documentation)? So that I can use variable like `file.path` and `file.modified_time` directly.

Previously when I was using Jekyll 2.x, I was doing something like below by creating my own asset directory.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/index.css" | prepend: site.url }}">
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have your gallery images in a structure like

```
-img
  -gallery
    -image1.png
    -image2.png
    etc.
```

you can access them in a collection or page like this:

```
{% for image in site.static_files %}
{% if image.path contains 'img/gallery' %}
    <p>{{image.path}} - {{image.modified_time}}</p>
    <img src="{{site.baseurl}}{{image.path}}">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This goes through all static files and check for a certain path (`img/gallery` in this example).

Than you can access the static file metadata for that file. (I named it 'image' in this example but you can name it whatever you want after the `for` keyword).

I think it doesn't make too much sense to put something like this in a blog post but rather in a `page` or a `collection`.

Answer (score 7):

A static file can be placed anywhere within the site directory that is not a collection of some sort. So not within a directory that begins with "_". What makes it static is the fact that it does not have YAML frontmatter.

Id recommend making a directory named "assets" or "images" and have them in there.

edit:

what are you trying to use the feature for?

Comment: I am trying to create an image gallery

Comment: how would you create this gallery? With a for loop?

Comment: Yes, That's what I am intend to do.

Comment: ok, did some more digging. You can have the files in any directory that is not a collection of some sort. id recommend having an assets folder. Will edit the answer.