# Managing Jekyll Pages in Folders (on github-pages)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, permalinks

I have a Jekyll website hosted on GitHub Pages. Now I am having so many pages and I would like to manage them in a folder called `_pages`. I ideally want to have this structure:

```
root
  |-> _pages
      |-> Index.md
      |-> contact.md
      |-> cv
          |-> cv.md
          |-> my_cv.pdf
  |-> _posts
  |-> [other things such as config and gemfile]
```

This I have done defining default permalinks in the `_config.yml` adding:

```
include:
  - _pages

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "_pages"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      permalink: /:basename/ # make URL of pages in the folder _pages as on the root.
```

That works perfectly.

However, as you see inside the `_pages` I would like to have another subfolder named `cv` and put my `cv.md` and `my_cv.pdf` in the same folder (in the actual website I have much more of these files for pages.). **Ultimately I would like to have a benefit of using `[Download my CV](my_cv.pdf)` relative local linking**, which I suppose because the pdf and the .md file are in the same folder it will recognize it. However it is not the case. `cv.md` has the permalink of /cv/ and not the **cv** folder. So when I use `[Download my CV](my_cv.pdf)` it creates `root/cv/my_cv.pdf` where this pdf file actually does not exist!

How can I manage to fix this thing? what is your trick?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put static files in a directory starting with an underscore. They will not be available in/after the build process:

[Which folder should I put my static files in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448853/which-folder-should-i-put-my-static-files-in-jekyll)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Solution one does not happen because the actual route for cv.md itself is in `_pages/cv/` where `my_cv.pdf` also is. So the global permalink changes the permalink of the `md` files and not the static_files.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Well actually they appear and are available even if you put them in an underscore named folder. The trick is to include the path in config.

Answer (score -1):

Unless this is something you plan to roll-out to dozens of sub-directories or dozens of sites, I'd just add the full path to the link. Something like `[Download my CV]({{ '/path/my_cv.pdf' | relative_url }})` or `[Download my CV]({{ '/path/my_cv.pdf' | absolute_url }})`.

Failing that, you could add `permalink: /path/where/pdf/lives/` in the `cv.md` frontmatter. This way they'll both be in the same directory. Of course, this means your `cv.md` won't build at example.com/cv/.